# Scraping Clean Scientific Names with No Parenthesis Using regex

Tags: python, html, regex, parentheses

I'm scraping scientific names from a website using regex, and I can't figure out how to not pull the parenthesis with the scientific name.

The HTML is written like this:

```
<span class="SciName">(Acanthastrea bowerbanki)</span>
```

My regex is written like this:

```
regex = '<span class="SciName">(.+?)</span>'
```

My results look like this:

```
(Acanthastrea bowerbanki)
```

But I need them to look like this:

```
Acanthastrea bowerbanki
```

Comment: can you post the code you are using?

Comment: Nickie hit the nail on the head, and I'm back in business.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an extra pair of parentheses, which you must escape with backslashes to make them literal characters:

```
regex = r'<span class="SciName">\((.+?)\)</span>'
```

You will use this as in:

```
import re

text = '<span class="SciName">(Acanthastrea bowerbanki)</span>'
regex = r'<span class="SciName">\((.+?)\)</span>'
m = re.match(regex, text)
print m.group(1)
```

Comment: That did it, although I omitted the "r" in: regex = r'<span class="SciName">\((.+?)\)</span>' What's that about?

Comment: The `r` stands for raw string notation; you can read more [about it](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) and also [why it's useful in regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague).  In this case it's not necessary as the backslashes in `\(` and `\)` are preserved.

Comment: That makes so much sense to me after a day of Python that I'm kind of embarrassed I asked the question, but it sure helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regex for this.

```
s = 'blah blah blah (Acanthastrea bowerbanki) blah blah blah'

scientistName = s[s.find("(")+1:s.find(")")]
```